# VAR model is predicting better one period ahead

Tags: forecasting, predictive-models, vector-autoregression

I am using a VAR(1) with two variables but it seems that the data forecast better one period ahead(blue line is the forecast, black line is the true value). Do you know why this happens?

the data is non-stationary, this could be the reason?

[image]

Comment: I suspect the series are not timed comparably. If you aligned the forecasts with their targets, you would usually see the forecast lagging, not leading. Here you have probably aligned the forecast origins rather than targets with the actual values.

Comment: Thanks Richard! I didn't align anything in the data or dates. I just took my data (two variables with weekly frequency) and used the VAR function in R. And when I checked the fitted plot for one variable I got that plot. I am just thinking that the period ahead (forecast) is closer to the true value one period behind. The variables are spend and revenue (context marketing) so they have a relationship. So my thought is that I can improve the model... but I don't know if I am correct or I should try another model.

Comment: Fitted values are not quite the same as forecasts, but the relationship is interesting nevertheless.